# Slide nested Divs in search bar

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I need to build a search bar that contains the search input, an Options button, and then a 3rd button when hovered expands to the left pushing the previous 2 elements over.

I have tried to do this with CSS but cannot get the other elements to slide over nicely so I am guessing this needs to be done with jQuery?

When the user hovers over the arrow the div slides open to the left to reveal the word 'search' along with a 20% gray overlay.

The 'options' button should slide to the left while the search button expands but the width of the entire search wrap should not change nor move.

[image]

[image: When hovered over arrow]

In terms of code this is where I am at right now:

HTML:

```
        <div class="search-box">
            <input name="" type="text" placeholder="search" class="input"><a href="#" class="option">options</a>
            <div id="search-button">
                <div id="search-button-text">search &nbsp;</div>
                <a href="#"><img src="/static/images/search-btn.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Some JS I tried without luck:

```
    $(".search-button").hover(function() {
        $('search-button-text').style.display = 'block-inline';
   });
```

The CSS:

```
.search-box {
    width:582px;
float:right;
clear:both;
}

.search-box .input {
float:left;
/*min-width: 500px;*/
border:1px solid #231f20;
height:25px !important;
font:16px "JosefinSans Regular", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin:0px;
}

.search-box .option {
    display: block-inline;
float:left;
    height:20px !important;
    width: 50px;
border:1px solid #231f20;
    padding-top:7px;
    text-align: center;
border-left:none;
border-right:none;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:13px;
}

#search-button {
    display:inline-block;
}

#search-button-text {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I think we need the CSS that goes along with this too

Comment: Yea sorry about that, forgot to include.

Comment: have you tried `.animate({width: 'toggle'});` ???

Comment: Yea when I tried that it pushed the search button down below the search box. The input and Options box didn't flex or resize when I tried that, breaking the layout.

Comment: also you missed the dot `$('.search-button-text')`

Comment: may be it breaked cause you have a fixed small width

Comment: I have a fixed width on the search wrap, the other interior elements don't have fixed widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done the slide effect through css3 transition property, Is this the output you are looking out for http://jsfiddle.net/T7FqG/1/ I have altered the html a bit and added the slide CSS

HTML

```
<div class="clearfix searchbox">


   <input type="text" />

   <a href="#" class="searchbutton">
        <span class="searchtext">Search</span>
        <span class="arrow">&#8594;</span>
   </a>
   <a href="#" class="option">Options</a>


</div>
```

CSS

```
        *{padding:0; margin:0;}
    .clearfix:after {clear: both;content: ' ';display: block;font-size: 0;line-height: 0;visibility: hidden;width: 0;height: 0;}
    .clearfix {display: inline-block;}
    * html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
    .clearfix {display: block;}
    .searchbox{width:500px;border:1px solid #000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;}
    .searchbox input{height:20px; padding:5px;border:0px solid #000; width:360px; outline:0;}
    .searchbox a{line-height:30px;  color:#000; float:right; display:block; text-decoration:none; padding:0 5px;}
    .searchbox a span{float:left; display:block;}
    .searchbox a.option{border-right:1px solid #000;border-left:1px solid #000;}
    .searchtext{width:41px;width:0; display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; -webkit-transition:300ms all;-moz-transition:300ms all;-o-transition:300ms all;transition:300ms all;}
    .searchbutton:hover .searchtext{width:45px;}
    .searchbutton:hover {background:#f2f2f2;}
```

Comment: Melwyn, this is great and I love the fact its all CSS and no JS. Is it possible to have the transition slide to the left instead of right, and in doing so pushes over the options box when expanded?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle link above in my answer, so that the search pushes the option button and slides in, have also updated the html and CSS code above. Check the new fiddle link in the answer above \m/